# Which of the following vector fields can be a gradient of a function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Which of the following vector fields can be a gradient of a function?

$A. F(x, y) = (2x + y, x + 2y)$

$B. F(x, y) = (2xy + y, x + 2y^2)$

$C. F(x, y) = (2x + y, x + 2)$

D$. F(x, y) = (\sin(xy),\cos(yx))$

I know that the gradient shows the direction of the biggest change of a function. I don't know how to approach this question. All I can say is that the vector field is basically the gradient at a given point.

Comment: What's your approach?

Comment: I know that the gradient shows the direction of the biggest change of a function. I don't know how to approach this question. All I cay say is that the vector field is basically the gradient at a given point.

Comment: Think of second derivatives and Schwarz lemma about commuting the second partial derivatives

Comment: Recall that the curl of a gradient is always $0$.

Comment: What is a conservative vector field and what are its properties?

Answer (score 0):

By the definition a vector field $\bf F$ can be written as a gradient of a scalar field $U$ if the condition $\nabla \times {\bf F} =0$ (the field is irrotational) where
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = \begin{vmatrix} \mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\  \\
{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}} & {\frac{\partial}{\partial y}} & {\frac{\partial}{\partial z}} \\
 \\  F_x & F_y & F_z \end{vmatrix} 
\\\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = \mathbf{i} \left (\frac {\partial F_z}{\partial y} - \frac {\partial F_y}{\partial z} \right ) + \mathbf{j} \left (\frac {\partial F_x}{\partial z} - \frac {\partial F_z}{\partial x} \right) + \mathbf{k} \left (\frac {\partial F_y}{\partial x} - \frac {\partial F_x}{\partial y} \right)$$.
So in your exercise you just need to work out the partial derivatives wrt x,y and see if they cancel out (or are zero)-all other terms are zero as you don't have z-component.
For example for the first field $A. F(x, y) = (2x + y, x + 2y)$,$\frac {\partial F_y}{\partial x} - \frac {\partial F_x}{\partial y}=1-1=0$, hence  $\nabla \times \mathbf{F}=0$ and the field can be written as the gradient of a scalar field.